# Plotly Dash - Why is base64 not in PyPI?

Tags: python, base64, background-image, plotly-dash

In Visual Studio, I've coded a python algorithm using plotly, in which I import base64 to encode a local image to use as figure background. It works in VS - also works in Google Colab -, I get the result and the graph I expect.

Unfortunately, when I try to create a Plotly Dashboard, the pip installation of base64 fails when running the `file_name.yml`. Indeed, 'base64' doesn't exist in PyPI.org, giving the following error in the VS terminal:

> **ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement base64==1.0.0**

*I've tried many versions, 1.0.0 is the last one.*

When I try to replace base64 with another library, such as `pybase64` or `b64`, the code doesn't work anymore.

Is it due to a specificity of the base64 library that I don't get? Is there any other library to do it?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Umm. `base64` is part of standard library python. You can't install it from PIP. and if you meant `pybase64` command should be `pip install pybase64`

Comment: I don't understand why I need to 'import base64' to make the code work if part of standard library...
I confirm it is not pybase64 I'm talking about :)

Comment: Do you mean [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) that can be used without using `import`? Python [standard libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/), e.g. `math`, `random`, `os`, .., `base64`, can be used using `import`.